# Using FastAPI & Pydantic, how do I define an Optional field with a description

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

For a FastAPI Pydanctic class I have these values

```
class ErrorReportRequest(BaseModel):
    sender: Optional[str] = Field(..., description="Who sends the error message.")
    error_message_displayed_to_client: str = Field(..., description="The error message displayed to the client.")
```

I use the class as an input model

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.post(
    "/error_report",
    response_model=None,
    include_in_schema=True,

)
def error_report(err: ErrorReportRequest):
    pass
```

When I run this, `sender` is a required field. If it's not included in the incoming JSON, I get a validation error.

Input:

```
{
  "error_message_displayed_to_client": "string"
}
```

Results in:

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "sender"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I remove the Field description like this:

```
    class ErrorReportRequest(BaseModel):
        sender: Optional[str]
        error_message_displayed_to_client: str = Field(..., description="The error message displayed to the client.")
```

the request passes.

How can I add a Field description to an optional field so that it's still allowed to omit the field name?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You'll need to provide an explicit default value to `Field`, for example `None` instead of `...`:

```py
class ErrorReportRequest(BaseModel):
    sender: Optional[str] = Field(None, description="Who sends the error message.")
    error_message_displayed_to_client: str = Field(..., description="The error message displayed to the client.")
```

`...` indicates that the value is required. This is of course in conflict with the `Optional`, but it looks like pydantic gives higher priority to `...`.

From the [documentation of `Field`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/schema/#field-customization):

> `default`: (a positional argument) the default value of the field. Since the `Field` replaces the field's default, this first argument can be used to set the default. Use ellipsis (`...`) to indicate the field is required.

Comment: thanks for saving me from sandtrap #427 for fastapi/pydantic/typehints noobs that isn't made clear by docs/books/tutorials  (this has been a frustrating experience)

Comment: also, that still leaves the problem of how to tell the difference between clients leaving the field out and clients explicitly setting the field to None

Comment: @odigity this answer might help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66231175/5768147